# TRIGGER SQL SERVER QUE ACTUALIZA TODOS LOS REGISTROS DE UNA TABLA

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Necesito que un trigger en sql server actualice todos los registros de la TablaX colocando en su columna llamada Indice un número entero consecutivo que comience en 1.  Es decir, si se inserta o elimina un registro de la TablaX y supongamos que la tabla tenga 100 registros.  Cada registro deberá quedar con un consecutivo que va del 1 al 100.  Si elimino por ejemplo el registro con indice 52, entonces el trigger debe nuevamente enumerar el campo Indice del 1 al 99.  Espero ser claro.

Este es mi código, pero no sé que poner en el WHERE.  Como hago que el While sepa cual es la línea que voy actualizando?

```
Declare @indice int
Declare @Total int

SELECT @indice=0
SELECT @TotalRegistros = count(*) FROM TablaX

WHILE @indice <= @Total
BEGIN
    SET @indice=@indice+1
    
    UPDATE TablaX SET Indice= @indice WHERE (no se que poner acá)
END;
```

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido  a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: La consecutividad depende de un orden, que fila es la 1 o la 2 o la 100 dependen de este orden, necesitamos saber la estructura de TablaX y saber cual el orden que determina el consecutivo.

Comment: El orden no interesa para la aplicación que le quiero dar.  O sea, si la tabla tiene 100 registros, no importa, cual registro sea el #1, cual el #2 y así sucesivamente.  Pero digamos que para facilidad podríamos ordenar por una columna que es llave primaria y que se denomina Id, y luego a la primer registro asignarle 1, al siguiente 2, y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Pero si aún así necesitas una estructura podemos hablar de que cada registro tiene 3 campos: Id (llave primeria, entero).  Indice (entero, donde se almacenara el consecutivo iniciando siempre en 1).  Descripcion (string).  A la TablaX se le pueden agregar o eliminar registros, y normalmente tendrá máximo unos 250 a 300 registros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres actualizar todos los registros de la tabla y dejarles un número consecutivo, no necesitas un `while`, puedes hacerlo masivamente con una única sentencia.

Esto no solo implica menos código sino que, dependiendo de la cantidad de registros, se va a ejecutar entre un poco, mucho o muchísimo más rápido que el ciclo.

Dado que parece que no importa el orden en el que queden, lo primero que me viene a la mente es algo como:

```
with
X as (
select TablaX.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) consecutivo
  from TablaX
)
update X
   set indice = consecutivo;
```

En el CTE `X` creo *al vuelo* un campo utilizando la función `row_number()`. Esta función exige que haya una cláusula `over` para indicar el orden en el que se numerarán, pero se le puede entregar `null`, con lo cual el orden queda sin definir, pero se cumple el requisito de la función<sup>1</sup>.

Finalmente, hago una actualización para establecer este valor *calculado* en el paso anterior al campo `numero` de la tabla subyacente.

Creo que puedes ajustarla a tus necesidades. Si quieres usar algún orden particular, solo cambia el `(select null)` que le paso al `order by` por la lista de campos por los que quieres ordenar.

---

<sup>1</sup> OJO que esto tampoco significa un orden aleatorio, en la práctica SQL Server va a entregar los registros en el mismo orden en ejecuciones consecutivas, pero es el motor quién define en qué orden las entrega y tu no tienes control directo sobre eso. Esto significa que el orden puede cambiar entre una instalación y otra, o entre una versión de SQL Server y otra. Incluso puede y va a variar entre ejecuciones en el mismo servidor a medida que se van insertando, actualizando y eliminando datos de la tabla.

Menciono todo esto, porque si lo que buscas es un orden aleatorio, entonces habría que tomar otro camino.

Comment: Hola Jachguate.  Tu solución me parece interesante porque es un código muy corto.  Pero me da error de sintaxis al tratar de implementarla.

Mi tabla se llama TablaX.
La estructura de mi tabla (3 campos) es: Id (llave primeria, entero). Indice (entero, donde se almacenara el consecutivo iniciando siempre en 1). Descripcion (string).

En la variable @indice almaceno el consecutivo, quien comenzaré en 1. No veo en tu código como va a comenzar en 1 (talvez no entendí).

Comment: Tu código lo interpreté así, pero me da error de sintaxis:


 with
 X as (
 select TablaX.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) Id
   from TablaX
 )
 update X
    set Indice = @indice;

El error de sintaxis me aparece en la línea 2 ("X as" se muestra en rojo) y en la última linea (Indice me aparece en rojo).

Comment: @Alejandro, edité mi respuesta para poner tu nombre de tabla y campos. No utilizo ninguna variable, así que `@Indice` no existe ni hace falta, sugiero que re-leas mi explicación y juegues un poco con el código, para entender como funciona. En la parte de jugar con el código, por ejemplo, con el mismo CTE, puedes lanzar un `select * from X`, así puedes observar lo que devuelve el CTE).

Comment: realmente el error de sintaxis no entiendo porque me salía, porque todo lo había puesto inicialmente como me lo envías ahora.  Lo que si es cierto es que ahora si me funciona perfectamente y lo mejor es que se usa poco código.  Eres un genio.   así quedó finalmente, tal cual lo escribiste arriba:     WITH 
 X AS (
  SELECT TablaX.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT null)) consecutivo
  FROM TablaX
 )
 UPDATE X
 SET Indice = consecutivo;

Comment: Excelente, me alegra ser de ayuda. Considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pues esto ayudará en el futuro a quienes lleguen aquí a identificar que la respuesta **si** fue de ayuda. Recuerda que en StackOverflow puedes saber, de esta manera, si hubo una respuesta útil y cuál es. Es muy útil cuando llegas aquí googlando un proximo problema. Esto no resta mérito a otras respuestas y en ocasiones habrá buenas o hasta mejores respuestas no aceptadas, pero si que ayuda. Si no sabes como aceptar una respuesta, haz el [tour].

Comment: No sabía como aceptar la respuesta, pero ya lo hice.  Nuevamente muchas gracias.  Este trigger lo voy a estar usando mucho para varios propósitos.  gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una posible solución a lo que preguntas.

```
Create table dbo.TablaX (id int primary key, indice int, col1 varchar(100))
Go
Insert into dbo.TablaX (id, indice, col1)
values
(1100,null,'a'),
(1101,null,'b'),
(1102,null,'c'),
(1103,null,'d');
Go
```

Con una tabla, ya existente.

Ahora hay que definir dos `triggers`, el de `insert` y el de `delete` (también, quizá se podría definir el de update, por si una sentencia aplica cambios en la columna, pero eso queda de tu lado, en principio no es necesario).

El `trigger` de `insert` puede ser algo similar a esto: Utilizamos una `cte` con `row_number` para numerar las filas entrantes, pero sólo **desde la última** que exista.

Aquí, en casos de elevada concurrencia, es apropiado incluir un nivel de aislamiento que nos permita, que dos inserciones con instrucciones diferentes, no nos devuelvan el mismo top(1).

[SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
Create trigger dbo.TablaX_Insert on dbo.TablaX
after insert
As
Begin
    
    With c as(
        Select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by id) as rn, id
        From inserted
    ), mx As (
        Select top(1)t.indice as mxId 
            From dbo.TablaX t
        order by t.indice desc
    )
    Update dbo.TablaX Set indice = mx.mxId +c.rn
    From c inner join dbo.TablaX t on c.id = t.id
        Cross join mx;
End
Go
```

Ahora el `trigger` de `delete`.

```
Create trigger dbo.TablaX_Delete on dbo.TablaX
after delete
As
Begin
    
    With c as(
        Select top(1)d.indice as mnId 
            From deleted d
        order by d.indice asc
    ), minX As (
        Select row_number()over(order by d.id) as rn, d.id as id 
            From dbo.TablaX d cross join c 
        where d.indice >= c.mnId
    )
    Update t Set indice = (minX.rn+ c.mnId)-1
            From minX inner join dbo.TablaX t on minX.id = t.id
            Cross join c ;
        
End
Go
```

Al igual que ocurre en el de `after insert`, sería interesante incluir un nivel de aislamiento, porque si dos borrados, se solapan en instrucciones diferentes, dará errores con la numeración.

Este `trigger`, solo numera desde el primer registro que contenga la sentencia de borrado. De manera que si la tabla tiene x millones de registros, no la reenumera entera.

Y por último la modificación de los registros existentes.

```
With c as(
        Select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by id) as rn, id as id
        From dbo.TablaX 
    )
Update t set indice = c.rn
From dbo.Tablax t inner join c on t.id = c.id;
```

Las tres partes de la misma, deberían de ir coordinadas, de manera que la `update`, sea la última, para que las sentencias `insert` y `delete` que ocurran antes no produzcan números que no ajusten.

Numeramos todos los registros para la columna `índice`, consecutivamente, ordenados por su `id`.

[image: Resultado]

Ahora procedemos a realizar varias sentencias.

```
Insert into dbo.TablaX (id, indice, col1)
Values
(1200,null, 'e'),
(1201,null, 'f');
```

[image: Resultado2]

Ahora procedemos con un borrado de los registros de id 1101 y 1103

```
Delete from dbo.Tablax where id in (1101,1103);
```

[image: Resultado]

La ordenación por id, tiene algunas particularidades que no se cubren en esta solución. Si el id es menor, podría no dar los resultados esperados, al reenumerar en el borrado.

Comment: Excelente solución.  Funciona perfectamente.  Muchas gracias